What does the definition “[[[Delete all values]]]” means under “Policy Setting” column of ”Policy Viewer tool?”
Does anyone know what the definition [[[Delete all values]]] means under Policy Setting column of Policy Viewer tool?
More specifically:

If i navigate through registry to the aforementioned path, I see that there are literally no values under DenyDeviceClasses registry key besides the (Default)  REG_SZ  (value not set) that exists under any Key in Windows registry, and the 1   REG_SZ that I manually added after tool's recommendation (next line).
To be more clear, the key DenyDeviceClasses key didn't even exist before I manually add it as well.

So, my question is, since the DenyDeviceClasses key didn't exist before I manually add it after tool's recommendation, why this line appears as there is a value difference between the current Effective state and the Baseline's recommendation (Grey Box next to [[[Delete all values]]] field under Effective State column). I even manually removed DenyDeviceClasses registry key completely and re-run the comparison, still same grey box appears in this line.
Any clarification on this would be greatly appreciated.

It’s probably just a value to display instead of displaying an empty string.
